# .NET CEF Sharp bindings WebSocket requests - OnBeforeResourceLoad method not raised/called

Tags: c#, websocket, cefsharp

I am using .NET (WPF and Windows Forms) bindings for the Chromium Embedded Framework(https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp). OnBeforeResourceLoad is unfortunately not raised/called for WebSocket requests in custom RequestHandler. Can anyone please assist me?

```
private sealed class BearerAuthResourceRequestHandler : ResourceRequestHandler
    {
        readonly IAuthenticationCredentials credentials;

        public BearerAuthResourceRequestHandler(IAuthenticationCredentials credentials)
        {
            this.credentials = credentials;
        }

        protected override CefReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IRequestCallback callback)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials.AccessToken))
            {
                var headers = request.Headers;
                headers["Authorization"] = $"Bearer {credentials.AccessToken}";
                request.Headers = headers;
                //request
                return CefReturnValue.Continue;
            }

            return base.OnBeforeResourceLoad(chromiumWebBrowser, browser, frame, request, callback);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So there are callbacks of the CEF does not work with WebSocket. Use DevTools.

Comment: Ok. @Staxcelrom can you please send any related example?

Comment: I don't use CefSharp, I use CEF. If you are satisfied with the CEF example, I can show you an example.

Comment: Sure.. Is it in c++?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
void OnAfterCreated(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser>my_CefBrowser_ptr) override
    {
            my_regestration_devtools(my_CefBrowser_ptr);
    }
```

...

```
my_regestration_devtools(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser>& browser)
{

    my_observer_class = new my_CefDevToolsMessageObserver_class(this); 

    CefRefPtr<CefBrowserHost> my_CefBrowserHost;

    my_CefBrowserHost = (*browser).GetHost();

    my_CefRegistration = (*my_CefBrowserHost).AddDevToolsMessageObserver(my_observer_class); 





std::string my_method = "Network.enable"; 


        CefRefPtr<CefDictionaryValue>my_CefDictionaryValue;

        int ExecuteDevToolsMethod_STATUS = browser->GetHost()->ExecuteDevToolsMethod(0, my_method, my_CefDictionaryValue);

}
```

...

```
    class my_CefDevToolsMessageObserver_class : public CefDevToolsMessageObserver
    {


    public:


        


    bool OnDevToolsMessage(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser, const void* message, size_t message_size) override
        {
   //Network messages will be sent here in accordance with the description of DevTools Chromium: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-webSocketFrameError

   //You need: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-webSocketFrameReceived
        }


        void OnDevToolsMethodResult(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser, int message_id, bool success, const void* result, size_t result_size) override
        {

        }


        void OnDevToolsEvent(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser, const CefString& method, const void* params, size_t params_size) override
        {
    //Network messages will be sent here in accordance with the description of DevTools Chromium: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-webSocketFrameError

   //You need: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-webSocketFrameReceived
        }


        void OnDevToolsAgentAttached(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser) override
        {

        }



        void OnDevToolsAgentDetached(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser) override
        {

        }

    private:




        IMPLEMENT_REFCOUNTING(my_CefDevToolsMessageObserver_class);
        DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(my_CefDevToolsMessageObserver_class);
    };
```